# Docker - Node, cannot find mysql module

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mysql-connector

I'm trying to create a docker with node, mysql and react on the front side. But when I try to import the mysql lib, I'm getting the following error:

```
const express = require("express");
const router  = express.Router();
const mysql   = require('mysql');
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'

I already check my node_modules folder and there is a mysql directory there.
This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-mysql": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12"
  }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile, I tried to install the mysql globally inside the container, but didn't solve:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12

WORKDIR /api

COPY package*.json /api/

RUN npm i -G nodemon
RUN npm install -G mysql
RUN npm install

COPY . /api/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    client:
        container_name: MY_api
        image: mhart/alpine-node:12
        build: ./client      
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        working_dir: /client
        volumes:
            - ./client:/client
        entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
        links:
            - api
        networks: 
            - MY_network
    api:
        container_name: MY_client
        build: ./api
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        working_dir: /api
        volumes:
            - ./api:/api
            - /api/node_modules
        depends_on: 
            - mysqldb
        networks:
            - MY_network
    mysqldb:
        container_name: MY_mysql
        image: mysql:8.0.19
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MY_PASS 
            - MYSQL_USER=USER
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=MY_PASS
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=MY_DATABASE
        networks: 
            - MY_network
networks:
    MY_network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: The `volumes:` declaration tells Docker that your `node_modules` directory contains vital user data that it must not modify; if you've recently added the package to your `package.json` file, Docker will not see the update because the old volume takes precedence.  If you delete that section of your `docker-compose.yml` file, it will run the code and library tree that's baked into your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your mounted volume `- /api/node_modules` from your docker-compose.

And remove those lines `RUN npm i -G nodemon` `RUN npm install -G mysql` inside your Dockerfile.

Everything should work fine